# Adding a key value into dictionary of list in python3

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.6

I have this data:

```
enquiry_metadata = {'enquiry_id': '02e19c4e21d2', 
'items': [{'status': 'SUCCESS', 'code': 0, 'panelId': '0a1702be81bf', 'data': {'customerId': 19373, 'appId': 30531, 'zip': 80124, 'service_id': 979869}}, 
{'status': 'SUCCESS', 'code': 0, 'panelId': '6e638d5fbb', 'data': {'customerId': 30743, 'appId': 51808, 'zip': 32425, 'service_id': 879463}}]}
```

How can I add the key:value `"companyId":"8424"` inside the list of dictionary `enquiry_metadata['items']`, to get a result like so?

```
enquiry_metadata = {'enquiry_id': '02e19c4e21d2', 
'items': [{'status': 'SUCCESS', 'code': 0, 'panelId': '0a1702be81bf', 'data': {'customerId': 19373, 'appId': 30531, 'zip': 80124, 'service_id': 979869}, 'companyId': '8424'}, 
{'status': 'SUCCESS', 'code': 0, 'panelId': '6e638d5fbb', 'data': {'customerId': 30743, 'appId': 51808, 'zip': 32425, 'service_id': 879463}, 'companyId': '8424'}]}
```

Comment: So idea is that a key-value pair should be added to *each* dictionary which is in some list of dictionaries? Do you know how to add it to a single dictionary? Do you know how to repeat code for each element of the list? If you put those two things together, does it solve the problem? "the best possible way to do it in case of huge data." If performance is a concern, the problem will be the data structure, not how you iterate in Python. If you need to change every element, then you need to change every element; the actual looping takes a tiny amount of time compared to the changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to iterate the items array then set the key/value of each:

```
from pprint import pprint

enquiry_metadata = {
    'enquiry_id': '02e19c4e21d2', 
    'items': [
        {'status': 'SUCCESS', 'code': 0, 'panelId': '0a1702be81bf', 'data': {'customerId': 19373, 'appId': 30531, 'zip': 80124, 'service_id': 979869}},
        {'status': 'SUCCESS', 'code': 0, 'panelId': '6e638d5fbb', 'data': {'customerId': 30743, 'appId': 51808, 'zip': 32425, 'service_id': 879463}}
    ]
}

for i in enquiry_metadata['items']:
    i['companyId'] = '8424'

pprint(enquiry_metadata)
```

and here it resulting output:

```
{'enquiry_id': '02e19c4e21d2',
 'items': [{'code': 0,
            'companyId': '8424',
            'data': {'appId': 30531,
                     'customerId': 19373,
                     'service_id': 979869,
                     'zip': 80124},
            'panelId': '0a1702be81bf',
            'status': 'SUCCESS'},
           {'code': 0,
            'companyId': '8424',
            'data': {'appId': 51808,
                     'customerId': 30743,
                     'service_id': 879463,
                     'zip': 32425},
            'panelId': '6e638d5fbb',
            'status': 'SUCCESS'}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
enquiry_metadata = {
    'enquiry_id': '02e19c4e21d2',
    'items': [{
        'status': 'SUCCESS',
        'code': 0,
        'panelId': '0a1702be81bf',
        'data': {'customerId': 19373, 'appId': 30531, 'zip': 80124, 'service_id': 979869}
    }, {
        'status': 'SUCCESS',
        'code': 0,
        'panelId': '6e638d5fbb',
        'data': {'customerId': 30743, 'appId': 51808, 'zip': 32425, 'service_id': 879463}
    }
]}

for item in enquiry_metadata:
    if "items" == item:
        for itemsItem in enquiry_metadata[item]:
            itemsItem["companyId"] = "8424"
            
print(enquiry_metadata)
```

output:

```json
{
    'enquiry_id': '02e19c4e21d2', 
    'items': [{
        'status': 'SUCCESS', 
        'code': 0, 
        'panelId': '0a1702be81bf', 
        'data': {
            'customerId': 19373, 
            'appId': 30531, 
            'zip': 80124, 
            'service_id': 979869
        }, 
        'companyId': '8424'
    }, {
        'status': 'SUCCESS', 
        'code': 0, 
        'panelId': '6e638d5fbb', 
        'data': {
            'customerId': 30743, 
            'appId': 51808, 
            'zip': 32425, 
            'service_id': 879463
        }, 
        'companyId': '8424'
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can also be done like this

```
    from pprint import pprint
enquiry_metadata = {
    'enquiry_id': '02e19c4e21d2', 
    'items': [
        {'status': 'SUCCESS', 'code': 0, 'panelId': '0a1702be81bf', 'data': {'customerId': 19373, 'appId': 30531, 'zip': 80124, 'service_id': 979869}},
        {'status': 'SUCCESS', 'code': 0, 'panelId': '6e638d5fbb', 'data': {'customerId': 30743, 'appId': 51808, 'zip': 32425, 'service_id': 879463}}
    ]
}

for item in enquiry_metadata['items']:
    item['companyId'] = '8424'

pprint(enquiry_metadata)
```

and the output will be

```
    {'enquiry_id': '02e19c4e21d2',
 'items': [{'code': 0,
            'companyId': '8424','data': {'appId': 30531,
                     'customerId': 19373,
                     'service_id': 979869,
                     'zip': 80124},
            'panelId': '0a1702be81bf',
            'status': 'SUCCESS'},
           {'code': 0,
            'companyId': '8424',
            'data': {'appId': 51808,
                     'customerId': 30743,
                     'service_id': 879463,
                     'zip': 32425},
            'panelId': '6e638d5fbb',
            'status': 'SUCCESS'}]}
```